# Calling a date with CONCATENATE is resolving to strange number

Tags: google-sheets, concatenate

Using:

```
=concatenate("Review Check on ", B2)
```

B2 is `4/20/2015`, that I created using the date insert shortcut (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd> on Mac).

The final cell resolves to:

> Review Check on 42114

The `/`s have been stripped and the number is strange.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All is considered a string when you concatenate elements. Therefore you need to format the text as a date. The following formula does that.

### Formula

```
="Happy " & TEXT(B2, "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

### Reference

[Google Spreadsheet help, TEXT()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en-GB&rd=1)

Comment: "MM/dd/yyyy" ;) I know it makes no sense that America writes dates this way.